# Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

Error logs from acer tablet, Acer B1-810 android 4.4.4.I was testing small BLE application , i got this log "Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan ", I am confused since BLE is introduced  in api level 18 (4.3) here am using Android 4.4.4 , but  "Could not find method android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan ". it shows in log.

Answer (score 3):

`BluetoothLeScanner` was added in api 21 for api below 21 use `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan()`

```
private void startBluetoothLeScan() {
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {

            }
        });
    } else {
        BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();
        List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilters, scanSettings, new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

refer to [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) documentation for more information